# Kill "HSSCP.exe *32" using batch

Tags: batch-file, taskkill

I'm fairly new to batch. I use the Hotspot Shield VPN, and noticed some extra processes running in the background even when it's not turned on (The whole application is shady to me, but I can't find any other reliable free VPNs.) The script I wrote: 
`taskkill /im hsscp.exe
taskkill /im fbwmgr.exe
taskkill /im fbw.exe`

There is another process called `HSSCP.exe *32` that shows up in Task Manager that I can't seem to end with  `taskkill /im hsscp.exe *32` Is this a different type of process? How would I terminate it?

Comment: That indicates that the process is running in 32 bit mode. You would still kill it with `taskkill /f /im HSSCP.exe`

Comment: [Examples](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)

Comment: Whoops. I don't know why it wasn't working earlier, but it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be killed with `taskkill /f /im HSSCP.exe` as normal, thanks @raney.

Answer (score 0):

The application can also be terminated using `hsscp.exe -quit`